# causes: failure to reinitialize video-out on resume

Tags: linux, graphics-card, bios, suspend

Hardware:

- DFI Lanpart NF4 SLI-DR
- PNY Geforce GT 730 (1GB GDDR5, HDMI/VGA out)
- HP 22es LCD

Black screen on S3 resume, both VGA-out and HDMI-out. I've gone through this checklist, [BEST PRACTICE TO DEBUG LINUX* SUSPEND/HIBERNATE ISSUES](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues). Not only are there no errors, the drivers seem to think the graphics card was properly re-initialized. I've tried kernels in the 2.x and 4.x series, and the NVIDIA, nouveau, and VESA drivers. I've swapped PCIe x16 lanes. Initially the graphics card was in the second x16 lane set to x8 (rather than x2) via the SLI jumpers. I even sawed a small portion off the heatsink so it could fit into the first x16 lane (setting the jumpers to single-GPU mode, x16). I've toggled all the relevant BIOS settings I could think of, mainly PCIe/PCI initialization.

The only logged warning is from gnome-shell: failure to get/set DPMS after resume. Obviously, because video-out fails to communicate with the display.

*Edit*:

Problem exists under Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some nouveau developers, the issue was determined to be a defective card.